# Checking if a value name for a key is present on the windows registry through batch file

Tags: windows, batch, windows-registry

I need help for verifying if the value for a key exist or not.

I don't know how to check if my specified value name exist or not in my specified Key path.
I have this:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\....." /v "ARCHIVELOGENABLE" /d "Y"
```

So, how to check if `ARCHIVELOGENABLE` is one of the value names in my Key path?

I have something like this:

```
@echo off
reg query myKEY > nul

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 echo (
  goto INSTALL
) else (
    if (my value name not exist) (
      goto INSTALL
    ) else (
      goto SKIP_INSTALL
    )
)
```

--my value name not exist, what should I write here?

Comment: Welcome to Super User!You have provided the work you have done before, which is useful; what problem are you running into specifically?

Comment: I think I do not understand your question, sorry.

Comment: I have to register a specified key path with a specified Key value name.
I have 3 cases:
1. if the key path does not exist, I should register the Key ad the value
2. if the key path dose exist, but my specified value name does not exist, I should register
3. if the key path does exist and the key value name exist and is different from my specified value, I should not registered

Comment: I think I need a for iteration for all the values from my Key, but, at this time I am totally confused

Comment: It is a plausible case that an user want to edit or delete the value name? and the installer should not overwrite it (in edit case)

Comment: Apologies for not being clear before. Where you have said "I need help", with what do you need help? For example, do you have error messages? Unexpected behaviour of your script?

Comment: I don't know how to check if my specified value name exist or not in my specified Key path

Comment: I have this:
reg add  "HKLM\SOFTWARE\....." /v "ARCHIVELOGENABLE" /d "Y"

Comment: so, how to check if ARCHIVELOGENABLE is one of the value names in my Key path?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1352646/edit) and update it with the details we have discussed.

Comment: reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE....." /v "ARCHIVELOGENABLE". If it doesn't exist %ERRORLEVEL% = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in your code and IF clause.

**Example**. Let's check `ForceActiveDesktopOn` value in key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

```
@echo off
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer /v ForceActiveDesktopOn > nul

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
echo Key not found 
goto INSTALL) else (
echo Key is found, skipping
goto SKIP_INSTALL
)

:INSTALL

:SKIP_INSTALL
```

You need also to insert your key name and value in reg query line